# MPMoviePlayerViewController not showing volume slider?

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am playing the video from the url:

```
   MPMoviePlayerViewController *m = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    if([m.moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsAirPlay:)])
        m.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:m];
```

It is playing, but there is no volume control slider. Is it possible to add volume control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MPVolumeView object.

```
volume = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: rect];
[self addSubview:volume];
```