# No UI controls for MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to add a video that I pull from my server do play in my app.

The video plays now, but I don't have any UI controls for volume. fullscreen etc.

Can any one help?  Here is my code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gzerodesign.com/sharksclips/video.mp4"];
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];

    if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {
        // Use the new 3.2 style API
        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlModeDefault;
        moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
        [[moviePlayer view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
        [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
        [moviePlayer play]; 
    } else {
        // Use the old 2.0 style API
        moviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;
        [moviePlayer play];  
    }
```

Comment: I have answered to a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5834370/503527

Answer (score 1):

I only have experience the New 3.2 style API.

`moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlModeDefault;`

comment out

`// moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlModeDefault;`

you may be have fullscreen button and skip button.
but not show volume.

I did not try but, I search this.

[MPMoviePlayerViewController not showing volume slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870907/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-not-showing-volume-slider)

Comment: none of that worked.. its weird, isn't the video supposed to play with default controls?

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line in your code:

```
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlModeDefault;
```

& also this line:

```
moviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;
```

& then check.